# WFC Rest service PUT with json -- received object is always null

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I have a simple windows serviced based WCF REST client (WebServiceHost() based).  I can receive data from a GET operation and I get a call to the right method on a PUT operation, however the passed json is not getting de-serialized into a .NET object.  I always get null for the passed object into my object.

The receiving method takes two parameters, one is a key from the uri and the second is to be the received json data.  The key comes into my method correctly.

I have logging turned on but there aren't any de-serialization errors.  Fiddler is happy, it receives a 200 response.  I don't see any funny stuff looking at what's going over the wire.

I've been looking at the other posts that revolved around this issue and from what I can see I have things set up correctly.  Obviously that isn't true but I cannot see what's missing / wrong.  This would be a lot easier if there were just a slight bit more diagnostic messages coming out. I have config file debugging set to verbose but I don't see much around the actual message de-serialization process.

Is there a way to tap into the actual de-serialization process to debug further?

Or is there something wrong with my setup detailed below?

Service contract, The `Send()` method has the two parameters, a `key` and a `message` object:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILoader
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Send/{key}")]
    string Send(string key, MessageBodyWrapper message);
}
```

I have the data contract setup for the message wrapper object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MessageWrapper")]
public class MessageBodyWrapper
{
    private string _messageBody;
    private string _state;

    public MessageBodyWrapper()
    {
        _messageBody = "un-initialized";
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Message")]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _messageBody; }
        set { _messageBody = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // Available in System.Web.Script.Serialization;
        return js.Serialize(this);
    }
 }
```

The interface

```
public class Loader : ILoader
{
    private string _state;
    public Loader()
    {
        _state = "initialzied";
    }
    public string Send(string key, MessageBodyWrapper Message)
    {
       string ret = "Send here -- Message";
       return (ret);
    }
}
```

I'm using fiddler to send out the sample PUT

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 48

{"Message":"sdsdfsdf"}
```

Comment: I added a ToString() method to my MessageBodyWrapper() class.  Then created a new object in my main and serialized it.  I then used that in Fidder as another test but that didn't help.  I really think there is some issue with my configuration that I cannot spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **JSON** is in incorrect format. Try this:

1. Change the `BodyStyle` in your **OperationContract** to `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`
2. Try adding following when request is made:

   `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8`
3. If still it doesn't work, then try **Overriding** `ToString()` method in your `MessageBodyWrapper` class.

   ```
   public override string ToString()
   {
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // Available in   System.Web.Script.Serialization;           
     return js.Serialize(this);
   }
   ```

Now make an object of `MessageBodyWrapper` and call `ToString()` method and here you can see your required **JSON** format.

```
MessageBodyWrapper mbw = new MessageBodyWrapper();
string json = mbw.ToString(); // Hit break point here and "json" variable will contain required JSON format.
```

After you get required **JSON** format, then try sending **JSON** in that format.

Hope this will help! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the json in incorrect format?  Also keep in mind my issue is receiving json not sending it.  Sending json is working.

Comment: Have you tried code above? Run this code string json = mbw.ToString(); It will show you right JSON that your service will accept.

Comment: I added the ToString() and create a new MessageBodyWrapper() in my main routine.  It serialized to this: {"Message":"sdsdfsdf"}  I still get null when sending that message from Fiddler into my code.  I really think there is a configuration issue somewhere in my code that I cannot spot.

Comment: Have you changed BodyStyle from Wrapped to Bare?

Comment: Changing the BodyStyle from Wrapped to Bare has the code working, I now can receive the json into the code correctly.  So the what is Wrapped used for?  For receiving only XML in the request body?  Additionally there are examples on the net that appear to be receiving json using Wrapped.  Do these programs somehow override this with other configuration somewhere else that makes it only appear to be using wrapped?  Regardless of all these questions, thanks for the help in getting it working!